# How to split a field in a CSV and duplicate the fields in the row to a new row

Tags: awk, sed, csv, text-formatting

I have a destination that consumes CSV files, and the 6th field contains words but the max char length is 16. If the field length exceeds 16 characters, I would like to duplicate the line and break it up without breaking the words.

**Current File**

```
"5","4","3","2","1","XYZ ABCD E"
"1","2","3","4","5","AB CDE F GHI JK LMNOP Q RS TUV W XYZ 12 3456 7890"
"9","8","7","6","5","LMN O PQ R"
```

**Desired Output**

```
"5","4","3","2","1","XYZ ABCD E"
"1","2","3","4","5","AB CDE F GHI JK"
"1","2","3","4","5","LMNOP Q RS TUV W"
"1","2","3","4","5","XYZ 12 3456 7890"
"9","8","7","6","5","LMN O PQ R"
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: May the fields of your csv files have embedded commas? Are all the fields always enclosed in double quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU Awk (`gawk`) to run `fold` through a [Getline/Variable/Coprocess](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fCoprocess.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fCoprocess)

```
gawk -F, '
  BEGIN{
    OFS=FS; 
    cmd="fold -sw 16";
  }

  # if total length (16 + 2 for quotes) is within limit, print as-is
  length($NF) <= 18 {print; next}

  # else
  {
    # trim the quotes, then fold
    print substr($NF,2,length($NF)-2) |& cmd; 
    close(cmd,"to"); 
    NF--; 
    while((cmd |& getline var) > 0){

      # (optional) trim trailing whitespace
      sub(/[ \t]+$/,"",var);

      print $0, "\"" var "\"" ;
    }
    close(cmd,"from");
  }
' file.csv
```

The `sub` removes trailing whitespace from the `fold` operation.

Note that to get the precise output shown, one would need to use `fold -sw17` to break at 16 characters plus the (subsequently removed) trailing space. However, doing so creates the possibility of exceeding the 16 character limit in the last line of folded output.

Comment: Nice. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Amazing, fold was exactly the right move.

Comment: @Steve thanks - I'm *slightly* disappointed that there doesn't seem to be a way to make it omit the space that it splits at (necessitating the extra `sub` operation)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a pretty lame awk script that preserves the double quotes.  Here it comes:

```
{
    for ( i=0; i<= length($6); i+=16 )
    {
        if ( i+17 < length($6) )
        {
            if ( i == 0 )
                printf ("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\"\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, substr($6,i,16))
            else
                printf ("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\"%s\"\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, substr($6,i+1,16))
        }
        else
        {
            if ( i == 0 )
                printf ("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, substr($6,i,16))
            else
                printf ("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\"%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, substr($6,i+1,16))
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
$ awk -F, -f awks csvfields
"5","4","3","2","1","XYZ ABCD E"
"1","2","3","4","5","AB CDE F GHI JK"
"1","2","3","4","5"," LMNOP Q RS TUV "
"1","2","3","4","5","W XYZ 12 3456 78"
"1","2","3","4","5","90"
"9","8","7","6","5","LMN O PQ R"
$
```

The only issue is that if there is a space at the boundary, it is preserved unlike the example where it has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below code and it worked fine too

```
 k=16;for ((j=1;j<=50;j++)); do  awk -v j="$j" -v k="$k" -F "," '{if(length($NF) > 16){print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,substr($NF,j,k)}else {print $0}}' filename; j=$(($j+16)); done|sort | uniq
```

output

```
"5","4","3","2","1","XYZ ABCD E"
"1","2","3","4","5","AB CDE F GHI JK"
"1","2","3","4","5","LMNOP Q RS TUV W"
"1","2","3","4","5","XYZ 12 3456 7890"
"9","8","7","6","5","LMN O PQ R"
```

Answer (score 0):

A SHELL only approach (tested on Bash and Ksh93).  However I do like the `fold` approach as it uses an extant tool.

```
# read from stdin, output to stdout
# Note no Shebang line at top so it made it easier for to try bash/ksh as interpreters

OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=,
while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6; do
    f6=${f6#\"}
    f6=${f6%\"}             # strip DQs
    if ((${#f6}<17)); then  # no action
            IFS="$OIFS"
            echo "$f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,\"$f6\""
            IFS=","
            continue
    else
            IFS="$OIFS"
            while ((${#f6}>17)); do
                    n6=${f6:0:16}
                    f6=${f6#$n6}
                    n6=${n6# }
                    n6=${n6% }
                    echo "$f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,\"$n6\""
            done
            echo "$f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,\"${f6# }\""
    fi
    IFS=","
done
IFS="$OIFS"
exit
```

Results:

```
"5","4","3","2","1","XYZ ABCD E"
"1","2","3","4","5","AB CDE F GHI JK"
"1","2","3","4","5","LMNOP Q RS TUV W"
"1","2","3","4","5","XYZ 12 3456 7890"
"9","8","7","6","5","LMN O PQ R"
```

To address the word break issue without using `fold` or similar, the following code should replace the commented out line shown below in the above.  Also replace the second `echo` command line with:

```
                    c6="$f6"
                    n6=""
                    while (((${#n6}+${#nw})<=16)); do
                            n6=$n6${c6%% *}\
                            n6=${n6# }
                            eval c6=\${c6\#${c6%% *} }
                            nw=${c6%% *}
                    done
                    #n6=${f6:0:16} ### replace by above
```

and replace

```
            echo "$f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,\"${f6# }\""
```

with

```
            ((${#f6}>0)) && echo "$f1,$f2,$f3,$f4,$f5,\"${f6# }\""
```

to avoid any null field 6 remainders occurring.

The following test file was used:

```
"5","4","3","2","1","XYZ ABCD E"
"1","2","3","4","5","AB CDE F GHI JK LMNOP Q RS TUV W XYZ 12 3456 7890"
"9","8","7","6","5","LMN O PQ R"
"1","2","3","4","5","A BB CCC DDD EEEE FFFFF GGGGGG HHHHHHH"
```

with results:

```
"5","4","3","2","1","XYZ ABCD E"
"1","2","3","4","5","AB CDE F GHI JK"
"1","2","3","4","5","LMNOP Q RS TUV W"
"1","2","3","4","5","XYZ 12 3456 7890"
"9","8","7","6","5","LMN O PQ R"
"1","2","3","4","5","A BB CCC DDD"
"1","2","3","4","5","EEEE FFFFF"
"1","2","3","4","5","GGGGGG HHHHHHH"
```

The use of the existing tools like `fold` however is much easier and follows the UNIX philosophy -- build upon existing simple tools.  But if you like Shell programming then the above is one way to get a solution.  If anyone needs explanations of the code please contact me.

Comment: BTW, I believe that @unxnut answer/solution does not handle keeping "words" together based on the results output.  I read the request as wanting to maintain words (which should therefore be <16 chars or my solution would fail).

Comment: And my above comment means of course that the use of fold is a MUCH better approach since you can easily make sure that words are not broken up.  My answer does not (yet) do that but does correctly do the test cases.